# what caching mechanism is best for asp.net MVC 5 when using async

Tags: c#, caching, asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-5

**1**

Basically, I'm trying to figure out what kind of caching mechanism is best (and easiest) for a asp.net MVC5 solution. 
In previous synchronious solutions, I have used a static dictionary,and the lock keyword when accessing it.

```
    private static Dictionary<string, object> _cache;
    private static object _cacheLocker = new object();

    private object GetFromCache(string key)
    {
        return _cache[key];
    }

    private void AddToCache(string key, object value)
    {
        lock (_cacheLocker)
        {
            _cache.Add(key, value);
        }
    }
```

But I think there must be a more elegant way of doing this in an async world.

**2**

What should I cache in an async method? Only the values or the values wrapped inside a Task

Thank you.

Comment: Caching has nothing to do with being asynchronous, but using a static Dictionary instance as a cache is a bad idea either way. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I know it's not a good idea. That's why I would like to stop my sins right now :-) For the second part of my question. Is there any gain of caching the values wrapped in Task ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using this method for my caching.

```
    protected ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
    protected T GetCacheOrExecute<T>(string key, Func<T> addToCacheFunction)
    {
        if (cache.Contains(key))
        {
            return (T)cache.Get(key);
        }
        else
        {
            T retValue = default(T);
            if (null != addToCacheFunction)
            {
                retValue = addToCacheFunction();
                var cachItem = new CacheItem(key, retValue);
                CacheItemPolicy policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
                policy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(30); //The cache time out
                cache.Add(cachItem, policy);
            }
            return retValue;
        }
    }
```

And I call it like this:

```
   public async Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetAllUsersAsync()
    {
        return await base.GetCacheOrExecute("users", doGetAllUsersAsync); //
    }

    private async Task<IEnumerable<User>> doGetAllUsersAsync() {
       //more code...
    }
```

Hope this helps...